# Port web-interface query to Python API when using BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery

So I have a query which I can execute (and get results) from the web interface. Next, I want to use this query inside a python script. However, this fails. Next are the details.

Assume this is the query used in the web interface.

```
SELECT
  MIN(visitStartTime)
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([123456789.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2017-02-22'), TIMESTAMP('2017-05-22')))
GROUP BY
  visitId,
  fullVisitorId
LIMIT
  1000
```

Next, I want to use this very query from Python. First, here are two utility functions (based on Google's references):

```
def async_query(query, project='ga---big-query', max_results=1000):
    client = bigquery.Client(project)
    query_job = client.run_async_query(str(uuid.uuid4()), query)
    query_job.use_legacy_sql = False
    query_job.begin()

    wait_for_job(query_job)

    rows = query_job.results().fetch_data(max_results)
    return rows


def wait_for_job(job):
    while True:
        job.reload()  # Refreshes the state via a GET request.
        if job.state == 'DONE':
            if job.error_result:
                raise RuntimeError(job.errors)
            return
        time.sleep(1)
```

Lastly, here's the querying:

```
query = """SELECT
  MIN(visitStartTime)
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([94860076.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2017-02-22'), TIMESTAMP('2017-05-22')))
GROUP BY
  visitId,
  fullVisitorId
LIMIT
  1000
"""

res = async_query(query)
```

This returns the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-1573194bda70> in <module>()
     27 # query = 'SELECT visitId FROM `94860076.ga_sessions_20170802`'
     28 
---> 29 res = async_query(query)

<ipython-input-33-e8addf14673a> in async_query(query, project, max_results)
      5     query_job.begin()
      6 
----> 7     wait_for_job(query_job)
      8 
      9     rows = query_job.results().fetch_data(max_results)

<ipython-input-33-e8addf14673a> in wait_for_job(job)
     16         if job.state == 'DONE':
     17             if job.error_result:
---> 18                 raise RuntimeError(job.errors)
     19             return
     20         time.sleep(1)

RuntimeError: [{'reason': 'invalidQuery', 'location': 'query', 'message': 'Syntax error: Expected "," or "]" but got identifier "ga_sessions_" at [3:34]'}]
```

I suspect that the problem is with the naming of the tables, but I don't know how to solve it. I did manage to port `SELECT visitId FROM [94860076.ga_sessions_20170802]` to `query = SELECT visitId FROM <backtick>94860076.ga_sessions_20170802<backtick>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is happening at this line:

```
query_job.use_legacy_sql = False
```

As you are using Legacy SQL, it should be:

```
query_job.use_legacy_sql = True
```

Or you could just leave it unassigned as the default value is `True`.

Still, it's highly recommended that you start using the [Standard Version SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/), it's way more powerful, stable and is also the recommended approach by the BigQuery team.

The Standard Version of your query would be something like:

```
SELECT
  MIN(visitStartTime)
FROM `94860076.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170222' AND '20170522'
GROUP BY
  visitId,
  fullVisitorId
LIMIT
  1000
```

Comment: Great catch! Can you give a hint how to translate the query I have to the standard version?

Comment: Amazing! If I understand correctly, in the web interface, the dialect is the legacy one. Is that correct?

Comment: In WebUI you can actually choose which version you want in the `Show Options` button. Here I use [BigQuery Mate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bigquery-mate/nepgdloeceldecnoaaegljlichnfognh) and have Standard Version defined as default.

Comment: Maybe you know how do I port `MAX(hits.transaction.transactionId)` to standard SQL?

Comment: This might be a bit more complex as `hits` is a ARRAY field so it has to be [UNNESTED](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays). I recommend asking a new question describing what you need and what you have tried so far so we can better help you.